# How do i add different classes to different elements in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, backbone.js

I have a div like so

```
<div id="test1">
<a id="hello1"> One</a>
<a id="hello2"> Two</a>
<a id="hello3"> Three</a>
</div>
```

I am using templates and backbone.js . Before rendering my view i want to check if the device is a iphone or ipad for which i already have a function. If it is a ipad i want to add seperate classes to each ANCHOR tag. i.e Class1 to hello1 , Class2 to hello2 etc. I have only 3 elements. I am very new at this so can somebody pls tell me how i can do this using Jquery/Javascript .

If by any chance there is someother info i should be providing pls let me know. I have a View.js and a Routing.js along with this. I tried using.

```
$("#hello1").addClass("Class1");
```

However this did not work . Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

EDIT - 
This is the View file

```
define([ "jquery", "backbone", "baseview", "template" ], function ($, Backbone, BaseView) {

"use strict";

var gohomeView = BaseView.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        this.constructor.__super__.initialize();

        this.events = _.extend({}, this.globalEvents, this.events);
        this.delegateEvents();
    },

    render: function () {

        var context = {
                pageName: 'Go Home'
            },
            partials = {
                header: this.globalPartials.header,
                tabbar: this.globalPartials.tabbar
            };



        $(this.el).html(templates["go-home"].render(context, partials));
        return this;
    }

});

return GoHomeView;
```

});

Comment: You missed a `"`: `$("#hello1").addClass("Class1");` that might be why it didn't work ;)

Comment: Is the missing of the `"` a typo?

Comment: Why are you not using media queries in your stylesheets? No extra classes needed.

Comment: Sorry my bad that was a typo which is not there in my code . espascarello i am using media queries however the styling of the buttons is different for both devices and i already have classes made from previous places in the app with these stylings. I am looking to avoid repeating the css again. Basically When u add the second class to the first one it becomes the ipad style. If i add both from the get go it wont work on iphone. My last resort is to copy the css and make another identical class . Is this the best way to go?

Answer (score 3):

Missing ending quote.

```
$("#hello1").addClass("Class1");
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo i have corrected it, In my code there is no typo. Would appreciate if you guys could give this another look

Comment: So you are saying that `$("#hello1").addClass("Class1");` doesn't actually add the class or it is and something else is going wrong?

Comment: It is not adding the class . I am very new at this and bacbone and i maybe the place where i am trying to do this is wrong. I have tried doing it where the page render function is present and i have also tried doing this before the page render function is called. I hope that made sense

Comment: No worries, we are here to help. Do you get any errors in your console? Sometimes if there is an error in one part of the code, it can prevent code that follows it from executing.

Comment: No there is no error. Kindly see my edit i hope it helps

Comment: are you sure the #hello1 a element is on the screen when you call the function?